# footer breaks on landscape view on small devices

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a footer which need to stay on the bottom of every screen, i have done it but the problem is it breaks on landscape view on small devices but on the portrait view it is working fine.

```css
  body, html {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }

  .footer {
    background: #0066cc;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="content">
        <h4><small>Powered by</small> <img class="footer-img" src="images/logo.png" alt=""></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want it to stay at the bottom of every device and on landscape also!!

Comment: Do you wish for the footer to be at the bottom of the page content or at the bottom of the viewport? Should it cover or displace content that is at the bottom?

Comment: i want it to stay at the bottom if the page

Answer (score 1):

I have done it with this code it stays on the bottom of the page on landscape as well as portrait

-first i did css on my container (main div)

```
.container{
min-height: 100vh; /* will cover the 100% of viewport */
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 100px; /* height of your footer */
width: 100%; }
```

-second i change footer css

```
.footer{
background: #0066cc;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%; }
```

and it fixed my problem .

by the way you don't get this problem every time but when you don't have enough content for your page footer will leave it's place and you'll get extra space on different devices even on the web view but when you have enough content for a page then footer will always stay at the bottom.

Comment: The issue with too little content could easily be remedied by adding `min-height:calc(100vh - 100px);` to the `.container` class

Comment: yes you're right i just made it too long and you don't need to make height:100% position: fixed; of body and html

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the way you position the footer. As you wanted in same position, the `fixed` instead of `absolute` will do the job.

```
body,html{
height: 100vh;}

.footer{
background: #0066cc;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%; }
```

Comment: it will come at the bottom but then it will move with the scroll on page